# vodka in my soda

Tags: adverbial-phrases

a. I had vodka in my soda.

b. I drank vodka in my soda.

Are these grammatically correct?

I think (a) is and (b) is not.

(a) would just mean there was vodka in my soda. I might not even have drunk it. Maybe someone served me a glass of soda with vodka in it and I noticed by the smell that there was vodka there and didn't drink it because I had to drive.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean grammatically correct or meaningful? Both sentences are grammatically correct, but the meaning of sentence b is not clear. If it's supposed to mean "I drank a mixed drink with vodka and soda", it doesn't mean that.

Comment: Your question mentions grammar (syntax), but the description of your reasoning is entirely about [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics). That’s like asking if “I’m on a sunny beach in Hawaii” is grammatical and suggesting that it’s not because in fact I am on the Siberian tundra in January.

Comment: Thank you both very much. Yes. I meant correct and meaningful. Sorry about that. I think (b) is grammatical, but not a sentence that expresses the meaning it's supposed to.

Comment: To 'have' a drink normally implies drinking it. In the scenario you describe, you would say something like "I could tell that there was vodka in my soda, so I didn't drink it."